# Differentiable function (independent of three tetrameters)

Tags: calculus

Designate all triple of real numbers $A,B,C$ such that function

$$f(x)= \begin{cases}  \frac{e^{4x} + Ax + B}{x^2} \quad x \neq 0 \\ C \quad \quad \quad \quad x=0 \end{cases}$$

is differentiable in $0$ and compute $f'(0)$ for all designated triples $(A,B,C)$.

I tried with difference quotient
$\dfrac{f(x_0+t) - f(x_0)}{t}$ where $x_0=0$ so difference quotient is equal
$ \dfrac{e^{4t}+At+B - C}{t^3}$.

I wish $$\lim_{t \to 0^{-}} \dfrac{e^{4t}+At+B - C}{t^3} = \lim_{t \to0^{+}} \dfrac{e^{4t}+At+B - C}{t^3} $$ and $$\lim_{x \to0^{-}} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = C,$$ 
but I have no idea how compute these limits. I will be grateful for each hint and idea.

Answer (score 2):

Let's write the Taylor expansion for the exponent near zero:

$$\frac{e^{4x} + Ax + B}{x^2}=\frac{1+4x+8x^2+\mathcal O(x^3) + Ax + B}{x^2}.$$
The continuity in zero yields the necessary condition that

$1+B=0,\quad 4+A=0,\quad C=8$.

It's up to you to check that these conditions are sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

First the function should be continuous at $0$:

For $x\ne 0$ we have:
$$f(x)=\frac{e^{4x}+Ax+B}{x^2}\sim_0\frac{1+4x+8x^2+Ax+B}{x^2}\to8=C=f(0)\iff A=-4 ; B=-1$$

and now we should verify that this function is differentiable at $0$
$$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{e^{4x}+Ax+B}{x^2}-8}{x}\\=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{4x}-4x-1-8x^2}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1+4x+8x^2+\frac{32}{3}x^3-4x-1-8x^2}{x^3}=\frac{32}{3}$$